# OS X Lion - Website sharing , display directory files

Tags: apache, web, osx-lion

I need some help to get Mac WebSite sharing to work as i want.

Basically i need to know how i can make it display the files of a directory.

Do i need to make a website to show my directory files or is there any other way ?

And if i do need to make a website to display my directory, what code should i use to do so ?

I am no expert on HTML **at all.**

Allso, i have been searching around for this and i couldn't find any answers related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a server-side language such as PHP, Java, ASP.NET if you want to display the 'servers' directory on a web page. I will say because you're a begineer use PHP as it's very easy to learn...

Download MAMP / XAMPP.

Research PHP and follow some tutorials first, and then implement directory searching and output it as HTML.
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php

## Code:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/

Comment: Ok, can you please refer me to a link or explain how this is done (My language is actually Object-c so this is very new to me)

Comment: you could use Objective-C to get directory information and output it as HTML. However you will only be able to view the .html locally to your machine unless you write a web-server in objective C :P

Comment: Hmm... seems like a lot of work. I can make an application instead which finds all the directory files and creates an .HTML file. How would the HTML file look like ? (Code)

Comment: np, hope you achieve your task.

Comment: Follow up; I got everything in place, now i need an id on every item shown (Like Item 1 has id 1, Item 2 has id 2 etc..)

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn indexes on in your Apache config. This could be on by default. Check to see if you have folder named Sites in your home directory. If you do rename the index.html page (if there is one) and then navigate to http://localhost/~yourusernamehere.

The same applies if you are using the default apache directory (the system wide one) which is located in /Library/WebServer/Documents if I remember correctly. In this case you would navigate to http://localhost. I just checked on my system (OS X 10.7) and the indexes were enabled by default.